# Are Pricebook and Pricebookentries available in Service cloud?

Tags: servicecloud, pricebookentry

Please let me know if these objects are available in service cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are.
Service cloud includes everything that Sales Cloud does.

Sales Cloud refers to the “sales” module in Salesforce.com. It includes:

- Accounts, Contacts
- Leads, Opportunities
- Reports, Dashboards
- Campaigns
- Tasks, Activities
- Products, Assets, Quotes
- Calendars, Events
- Forecasts, Territory Management
- Chatter
- Custom Apps, Tabs & Objects
- Self-Service Portal
- Public Knowledge (via Communities)
- CTI Integration (more service-focused)
- Cases, Solutions
- Visual Workflow
- Add-On: Knowledge Base
- Add-On: Service Cloud Portal

Service Cloud includes everything that Sales Cloud does and adds the additional:

- Service Cloud Console
- Service Entitlements
- Service Level Agreements
- Visual SLA Timelines
- Add-On: Live Agent
- Omnichannel Routing
- CTI integration
- Web-to-case
- Add-On: Live Messaging

[Source](https://ledgeviewpartners.com/blog/salesforce-service-cloud-vs-sales-cloud/).

In order to get the [List of Standard Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) you could start from [Service Cloud Developer Center](https://developer.salesforce.com/developer-centers/service-cloud/) then look at "Dive Deeper" section and click on [SOAP API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm) then expand "Reference", and click on "Standard Objects". There you'll find both Pricebook2 and PricebookEntry.
In those pages is stated what do you need to use such objects, if they have requirements. I.E. [JobProfile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_jobprofile.htm) needs Field Service.

In [Filed Service Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.field_service_dev.meta/field_service_dev/fsl_dev_soap_core.htm) you can see this image which show Pricebook and PricebookEntry as Sales and Service objects.
[image: standard_data_model]

Even in [FSC documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_admin_guide.meta/financial_services_cloud_admin_guide/fsc_admin_data_model_diagram.htm) you can see that standard objects are referred as "Sales or Service Object" in these two images [data_model_1](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/resources/img/en-us/228.0?doc_id=help%2Ffinserv%2Fimages%2Ffsc_data_model_base.png&folder=financial_services_cloud_admin_guide) and [data_model_1](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/resources/img/en-us/228.0?doc_id=help%2Ffinserv%2Fimages%2Ffsc_insurance_data_model.png&folder=financial_services_cloud_admin_guide).

More info on [developer.salesforce.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BTWqIAO) and [here](https://www.akacrm.com/blog/49-sales-cloud-vs-service-cloud).

Comment: RubenDG, Thanks for the response , But is there any documentation where it is mentioned

Comment: @user91530  [List of Standard Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm). Docs about [Pricebook and Pricebook Entry](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=products_fields.htm&type=5) in Sales Cloud. Moreover there is the link to [developer.salesforce.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BTWqIAO) posted in the answer.

Comment: I checked both the datamodel as shared by you but can't see the pricebook and pricebookentry objjject in the diagram. could you please suggest.

Comment: @user91530: Please open [Service Cloud Developer Center](https://developer.salesforce.com/developer-centers/service-cloud/) then look at "Dive Deeper" section and click on [SOAP API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm) then expand "Reference", expand "Standard Objects" and search for "Pricebook2"

Comment: @user91530 [Here you go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea8wI.png). I took it from [Field Service docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.field_service_dev.meta/field_service_dev/fsl_dev_soap_pricing.htm)

Comment: Thank you so much RubenDG.

Comment: They are included in datamodel in both licenses, BUT can they be used according to contracts? I know that for example for Case object, not having bought ServiceCloud license and according to contract you cant use it to operate customer inquiries as you would do normally having ServiceCloud.